# MVC Get ActionFilterAttribute value in Base Controller OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute, onactionexecuting

If i set an Attribute on an action in a controller that inherits BaseController, is it possible to get that value in some BaseController function?

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {  ....  want to get the value of DoNotLockPage attribute here?  }



public class CompanyAccountController : BaseController
{
        [DoNotLockPage(true)]
        public ActionResult ContactList()
        {...
```

Answer (score 2):

Took a different route.
I could have simply created a variable in the basecontroller and set it to true in any action. 
But i wanted to use an Attribute, just easier to understand code.
Basically in the basecontroller i had code that would lock the page under certain conditions, view only.
But being in the base class this would effect every page, there were a couple actions i needed always to be set to edit.

I added a property to the basecontroller.
And in the OnActionExecuting of the Attribute, i'm able to get the current controller and set it the property to true.

This way i was able to get my attribute setting in my override of ViewResult.

My Attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class DoNotLockPageAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly bool _doNotLockPage = true;

    public DoNotLockPageAttribute(bool doNotLockPage)
    {
        _doNotLockPage = doNotLockPage;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var c = ((BaseController)filterContext.Controller).DoNotLockPage = _doNotLockPage;
    }
}
```

My base controller

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public bool DoNotLockPage { get; set; } //used in the DoNotLock Attribute

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {  ......  }

    protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
    {
        var m = model;

        if (model is BaseViewModel)
        {
            if (!this.DoNotLockPage) 
            { 
                m = ((BaseViewModel)model).ViewMode = WebEnums.ViewMode.View; 
            }
            ....
            return base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
        }

    }
}
```